# Novice with jQuery AJAX

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax

I am simply learing Ajax with jQuery and have a simple page method that takes in a parameter and returns a string. For some reason, I am not getting the return string but I am getting to my 'success' message:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "testFormMatt.aspx/sayHello",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: '{"name": "matt"}',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(msg) {
                    $.jGrowl('The web service has been successfully called');
                    $('#result').append(msg);
                }
            });
});
```

Comment: You sure the return string contains anything? try just `alert(msg);`

Comment: Are you saying that msg is 'success' and that 'success' is being appended to #result? Or are you saying that your success jGrowl is firing but nothing is being appended to #result?

Comment: jGrowl says success but there is nothing being appended to #result. [object Object] is coming back from asp.net method when I use alert(msg). Guess that's where my problem is?

Comment: For kicks, try `alert(eval(msg));`

Comment: It would say [object Object] if, for example, your page were returning a JSON result. If that's the case, you'll need to call whatever property of msg you'd like to use when appending.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `append`, you need to specify the property of the JSON object that you want to append.

So if your page is returning:

```
{ message: "Hello, Matt" }
```

Then you'd need to call append like this:

```
$("#result").append(msg.message);
```

If your page is not returning JSON, then you need to take the `dataType: "json"` out of the `$.ajax` call. The `dataType` parameter is for specifying the expected data type of the response, not the data type of the request.

Comment: Ok, cool. Didn't know that about the dataType: "json". I am now getting this back in my alert. 

{"d":"hello matt."}

How do I clean that up?

Comment: Your result is JSON so you need to leave 'dataType: "json"' in there. If your property is called d, you'd want to call $("#result").append(msg.d);